# Python map reduce match partial key in Dictionary and sum values

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am trying to sum values in a dictionary based on partial key matches. My dict  `cust_dictionary` looks like this with the key as `month;Country:customer_id` and then the values is a sales amount

```
:|{'07;EIRE:14156': 26468.0, '09;United Kingdom:16266': 102.0,'07;EIRE:12600': 124.0
```

and I have a list of partial keys `uniq_cust` like this:

```
:|['07;EIRE', '09;United Kingdom', '06;United Kingdom', '03;Germany', '04;Finland',
```

Would I iterate thru the dict using the list of keys and sum that way? What would that look like?

and I want to match the partial keys to the dict and sum each match so I would be left with something like this:

```
07:EIRE,14280
09:United Kingdom,16266
```

Comment: How do you get to 14280? Looks like you add 14156+124, but this is adding two different types of numbers. For EIRE I could see adding the dict values 26468+124 or the values in the keys 14156 + 12600. But you seem to be arbitrarily mixing the two, which is not extrapolatable to other situations.

Comment: my mistake - I was looking at the wrong number. It is adding 26468+124. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
result = {}
for key,dict_value in custom_dict.items():
    partial_key, rest_key_value = key.split(':')
    if not partial_key in result:
        result[partial_key] = 0
    #not super clear from your question if you want to add the numbers within the keys or the number associated to the keys via the dict
    
    #next commented out line is adding the values included in the keys themselves
    #result[partial_key] += int(rest_key_value)
    
    #next line is adding the values in the dict
    result[partial_key] += dict_value
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to add the value of the key and this should do it.